# Ibatis and Oracle limit resultset

Tags: oracle, ibatis

i have to change a sql mapping in Ibatis an I want to limit the resultset to 1000 rows for every of tipe "list".

I tried this:

```
<select id="list" parameterClass="common.dto.Dto" resultClass="common.Entity">
        SELECT *
        FROM table SOC
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SOCIETASEP SEP
        ON SEP.COSOCIETA = SOC.CODSOCIETA

        <dynamic prepend="WHERE">

        ROWNUM&lt;=1000

    <isNotEmpty prepend="AND" property="ragSoc">
        DSRAGSOC LIKE UPPER(#ragSoc#) || '%'
    </isNotEmpty>
        </dynamic>
</select>
```

But doesn't work. Ho to insert a static condition?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace :

```
ROWNUM&lt;=1000
```

by:

```
<![CDATA[ ROWNUM <= 1000 ]]>
```

Something likes this:

```
<select id="list" parameterClass="common.dto.Dto" resultClass="common.Entity">
        SELECT *
        FROM table SOC
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SOCIETASEP SEP
        ON SEP.COSOCIETA = SOC.CODSOCIETA
        where       
<![CDATA[ ROWNUM <= 1000 ]]>

    <isNotEmpty prepend="AND" property="ragSoc">
        DSRAGSOC LIKE UPPER(#ragSoc#) || '%'
    </isNotEmpty>

</select>
```

HTH.